# JNI C++ to Java 32 bit image not showing properly

Tags: java, c++, colors, bitmap, java-native-interface

I have the following C++ code for JNI

And the following Java code to create a 32bit bufferedimage, the sizes are also received through JNI

Everything seems to work only that I have some weird colors in the image and I don't know how to get it right

Result of an image:

Comment: Looks like you would need a few more minutes in a channel mixer finding out which RGB -> {BGR,BRG,RBG,GBR...} is correct. Perhaps a value invert would also be needed (mind you: I haven't read anything about the format(s) involved. Just going by the way the screenshot looks now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this just a mix in the order of the color components?

I'm not familiar with any of these functions, but I believe that `DIB_RGB_COLORS` gives you the components in the [“blue, green, red, reserved”](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) order, whereas `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` is expecting the components in the [“alpha, blue, green, red”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR) order.

Comment: This must be because of the 4th byte (reserved / alpha). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How would I go around that seeing there only is a TYPE_4BYTE_ABRG and TYPE_4BYTE_ABRG_PRE and both don't seem to work.

Comment: If `bi.biCompression` is `BI_RGB` after calling `GetDIBits`, then I guess you could manually swap the bytes in `rawPixels` (interpret it as `__int32*` and run `*pixel = (*pixel >> 8) | (pixel << 24)` on each 4-bytes pixel). If `bi.biCompression` is *not* `BI_RGB`, then the pixels may be RLE-compressed and it'll be more complex.

Comment: Isn't this possible in Java by creating an 'IndexColorModel'. I do really want to send bytes to keep the performance as high as possible. I'm not into graphics and all help is welcome

Comment: Or should I use DIB_PAL_COLORS and create a HPALETTE and shift pixels accordingly? How would I go around that?